# C function syntax

Tags: assembly, glibc

On this page : http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/libc/sysdeps/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c

I see these two lines :

```
extern void restore_rt (void) asm ("__restore_rt") attribute_hidden;
extern void restore (void) asm ("__restore") attribute_hidden;
```

What is this syntax? Is it setting up `restore_rt` to be a function that has inline `asm("__restore_rt")` as its body?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's a way to replace the symbolic name of a C function...

> In order to change the name of a function, you need a prototype declaration, because the compiler will not accept the asm keyword in the function definition:

```
extern long Calc(void) asm ("CALCULATE");
```

> Calling the function Calc() will create assembler instructions to call the function CALCULATE.

Search for "Replacing symbolic names of C functions" in [this document](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html)

Answer (score 4):

Using `asm` in a function declaration is a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) extension (also supported by [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) called [asm-label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html). It is setting the assembler and linker known name of the function.

BTW, in your code `attribute_hidden` is probably a macro for some [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), probably [`__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)